# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Can't stop process; it's not currently running

Tags: android, adb, appium

Getting this error on jenkins job console when my test cases is running with Appium and java.Checked that appium server is up and running 
Appium version 1.8.1

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. Original error: Can't stop
>   process; it's not currently running (cmd:
>   'D:\SDK\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe') (WARNING: The server did not
>   provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 1.83
>   seconds

Comment: Check logs on the server side for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up Jenkins make sure that you have set all the 'dependancies' and environment variables on the machine hosting Jenkins.

login>Manage Jenkins>Configure System >Tick the env variables and add the paths there.

Once I did that my server started running and I had no issues . Also I would check that all the paths to the android sdk tools, Java JDK, nodeJS and appium.

Lastly I would see if I can kick off a job via command line on the machine to see if the machine hosting Jenkins is set up correctly.(If not then this will give you a better error message and indication as to what exactly the issue is)

Comment: thanks ..I have set up Path correctly still i face this very rare..with same environment